# Bisector proof in an olympiad level problem

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I simplified this from a problem in IMO Shortlist:

The incircle Ω of the acute-angled triangle  is tangent to  at . Let  be an altitude of triangle  and let  be the midpoint of . If  is the other common point of Ω and , prove that *NK* is the bisector of angle *BNC*.

[image]

I have no idea on this. I tried by analytic and trigonometric way but the incircle radius is too complicated. Are there any euclidean tricks to solve it?

Comment: while there seems to be an easier solution, even trigonometry / analytic approach should work. Can you share your attempt so we can see where you got stuck?

Comment: I'm trying to write the equation of the incircle but the equation is too complicated. This equation should be combined by the line equation NK then solve 2 roots (N and K).

Comment: Try and show $BN: NC = BK:KC$. For that, try and use power of point and intersecting chords.

Comment: This is a very beautiful geometry problem, could you please provide more details on the year, author (country proposing the problem at least), and the source for the problem?! Thanks!

Comment: https://imomath.com/index.php?options=323 (Problem 14) https://anhngq.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/imo-2002-shortlist.pdf (G7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to give two solutions, one solution is purely geometric, one is (very) analytic in its nature and its computational aspect. If the geometric solution is known, who needs an other one? Well, i am writing a book on computer algebraic support for proofs of results of all kind, and this is a wonderful example. With a computational engine the proof is easy and algorithmic. (Although it gives no geometric insight and destroys the beauty of the problem.)

---

**The geometric solution.**

Let $a,b,c$ be as usual the lengths of the sides in $\Delta ABC$, and let $s=\frac 12(a+b+c)$ be the semiperimeter. Then $BK=s-c$ and $CK=s-b$. We have to show that $NK$ is the angle bisector in $\Delta NBC$. To get the idea for the (construction involved in the) proof, let us step back and ask for the geometric locus of all points $P$ having "this property", i.e. the locus of $P$ such that $PK$ is the angle bisector in $\Delta PBC$. By cartesian considerations, letting $P=P(x,y)$ have the coordinates $x,y$, we obtain the equation (with obvious notations of the coordinates for $B,C$...)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{PB^2}{PC^2} 
&=
\frac{KB^2}{KC^2}\ ,\qquad\text{i.e.}\\
\frac
{(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2}
{(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2}
&=
\frac{(s-b)^2}{(s-c)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
In case of $b=c$ the triangle is isosceles, the lines $AK$ and $AD$ coincide with the side bisector of $BC$, so $N$ is on this side bisector, and the result is easy. Else, $b\ne c$, and we may and do assume $b>c$, so that we are in the situation in the picture. Then the above equation in $(x,y)$ has degree two, the term $xy$ does not appear, and the terms in $x^2$ and $y^2$ have the same non-vanishing coefficient. The geometric locus of $P$ is thus a circle. By the reflection symmetry w.r.t. the line $BC$ for the property of $P$, this circle is symmetric w.r.t. $BC$, so its center $\Omega$ is on $BC$. Here is the picture so far:

[image: math stackexchange problem 4252594]

The point $K\in BC$ is one point on this circle. Which is the other point $K'\in BC$? It is a point satisfying
$$
\frac{K'B}{KB} 
=
\frac{K'C}{KC}
=
\frac{K'C-K'B}{KC-KB}
=
\frac{a}{(s-c)-(s-b)}
=
\frac{a}{b-c}\ .
$$
This implies
$$
\frac{s-b}{b-c}
=\frac{BK}{b-c}
=\frac{K'B}a
=\frac{K'B+BK}{a+b-c}
=\frac{K'K}{2(s-c)}\ ,
$$
so the radius of the circle $(\Omega)$ is
$$
\Omega K =\frac 12 K'K=\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{b-c}\ .
$$
Let us now address the point $N$. The given problem wants us to show that $N$ is on the circle $(\Omega)$. It turns out (and this can be immediately observed in a faithfull picture), that $\Omega K$ and $\Omega N$ are two equal segments, and (their lines) are tangent to the incircle $(I)$ in $K$, respectively $N$. Let us show this. This property is equivalent to
$$
\Omega I\perp KMN\ ,
$$
and in this version, $\Omega I\perp KM$ we have eliminated $N$ from the discussion, and need to show a property in terms of the less involved point $M$. This is equivalent to $\angle MKD=\angle \Omega IK$, so let us compute using standard notations in a triangle
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cot\widehat{MKD}
&
=\frac{DK}{DM}
=\frac{BK-DK}{AD/2}
=\frac{a((s-b)-c\cos B)}{a\cdot AD/2}
\\
&=\frac1{[ABC]}
\cdot \frac 12\left(\ a(a+c-b)-(a^2+c^2-b^2)\ \right)
\\
&=\frac1{[ABC]}
\cdot \frac 12(b+c-a)(b-c)
=\frac{(s-a)}{[ABC]}
\cdot(b-c)\ .
\\
\cot\widehat{\Omega IK}
&=\frac{IK}{\Omega K}
 =\frac{r(b-c)}{(s-b)(s-c)}
 =\frac{[ABC]}{s(s-b)(s-c)}\cdot(b-c)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The two cotangents are equal because of the formula for the squared area (Heron):
$$
[ABC]^2 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\ .
$$
$\square$

---

We are done, but...
The OP comes with an effort to solve the problem by using analytic tools, however the complexity is overwhelming. For this and only this reason, let us pass the maths & programmers Olympiad, so here is a solution using barycentric coordinates, b.c. for short in the sequel.

Take a look at [bary-short.pdf](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-short.pdf) for a quick, excellent introduction. Here are some words on b.c. - the reader may please skip the passage if this is no issue at all.

The normed b.c. of a point $P$ is a triple $(x,y,z)$ so that (more or less formally) $P=xA+yB+zC$. (E.g. by passing to complex numbers, or using this as a short cut for the vectorial writing $OP=xOA+yOB+zOC$, for some/any $O$.) Here, normed means $x+y+z=1$. Sometimes we relax this condition, denote the coresponding (possibly unnormed, projective) b.c. by $[x:y:z]$, and there is a simple passage to the normed b.c. by dividing the components $x,y,z$ by $(x+y+z)$, so this makes sense only in case $x+y+z\ne 0$. Using projective coordinates makes sense, since all geometric objects (like lines, circles, etc.) have a corresponding homogeneous equation in the b.c. unknowns $x,y,z$.
OK, let's start.

---

Let $a,b,c$ be the sides of the given triangle $\Delta ABC$.
Let $s=\frac 12(a+b+c)$ be the semiperimeter. Then the incircle has the equation

$$
\tag{$\diamondsuit$} a^2yz + b^2zx + c^2xy = 
(x+y+z)\left(\ (s-a)^2x + (s-b)^2y + (s-c)^2z \ \right)\ .
$$

The needed points are:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= (1,0,0)\ ,\\
B &= (0,1,0)\ ,\\
C &= (0,0,1)\ ,\\
K &= [0:s-c:s-b]\ ,\qquad\text{ and it verifies $(\diamondsuit)$ ,}\\
D &= [0:\tan B:\tan C]\\
&=\left[0\ :\ \frac{\sin B}{\cos B}\ :\ \frac{\sin C}{\cos C}\ \right]\\
&=\left[0\ :\ 
\frac{b}{(a^2+c^2 -b^2)/(2ac)}\ :\ 
\frac{c}{(a^2+b^2-c^2)/(2ab)}\ \right]\\
&=[0\ :\ a^2 +b^2-c^2\ :\ a^2-b^2 +c^2\ ]\ ,\\
&=\left(0\ ,\ \frac 1{2a^2}(a^2 +b^2-c^2)\ ,\ \frac 1{2a^2}(a^2-b^2 +c^2)\ \right)\ ,\\
M &= \frac 12(A+D)\\
&=\left(\frac 12\ ,\ \frac 1{4a^2}(a^2 +b^2-c^2)\ ,\ \frac 1{4a^2}(a^2-b^2 +c^2)\ \right)\ ,\\
&=[2a^2\ :\ a^2+b^2-c^2\ :\ a^2-b^2+c^2]\\
&=\left[a^2\ :\ \frac 12(a^2+b^2-c^2)\ :\ \frac12(a^2-b^2+c^2)\right]\\
&=[a^2\ :\ S_C\ :\ S_B]\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

The last line comes with the Conway notations ($S_B$ and $S_C$, defined as used).
Now after solving the equations $(\diamondsuit)$ and the equation of the line $KM$

$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
0 =
\begin{vmatrix}
  x&y&z\\
  0&s-c&s-b\\
  a^2 & S_C & S_B
\end{vmatrix}
$$

it turns out that $N$ has (against my expectation) a rather "simple" expression (in homogeneous, unnormed b.c.):
$$
N = [x_N:y_N:z_N] = [ a^2(s-b)(s-c)\ :\ (s-a)(s-c)^3\ :\ (s-a)(s-b)^3]\ .
$$
Let us explicitly check $(\dagger)$ for $N$.
The relation $\sim$ used below means "up to a (known) factor".
$$
\begin{aligned}
&
\begin{vmatrix}
  x_N&y_N&z_N\\
  0&s-c&s-b\\
  a^2 & S_C & S_B
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
  a^2(s-b)(s-c) & (s-a)(s-c)^3 & (s-a)(s-b)^3 \\
  0&s-c&s-b\\
  a^2 & S_C & S_B
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&\qquad \sim
\begin{vmatrix}
  (s-b)(s-c) & (s-a)(s-c)^3 & (s-a)(s-b)^3 \\
  0&s-c&s-b\\
  1 & S_C & S_B
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&\qquad \sim
\begin{vmatrix}
  0 & (s-a)(s-c)^3 - (s-b)(s-c)S_C & (s-a)(s-b)^3 - (s-b)(s-c) S_B\\
  0&s-c&s-b\\
  1 & * & *
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&\qquad \sim
\begin{vmatrix}
  (s-a)(s-c)^2 - (s-b)S_C & (s-a)(s-b)^2 - (s-c) S_B\\
  1 & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&\qquad \sim
(s-a)((s-c)^2-(s-b)^2) -s(S_C-S_B) + (bS_C-cS_B)
\\
&\qquad \sim
(s-a)a(b-c) -s(b-c)(b+c) + \frac 12(a^2+b^2+c^2+2bc)(b-c)
\\
&\qquad \sim
a(s-a) - \frac 12(a+(b+c))(b+c) + \frac 12(a^2+b^2+c^2+2bc)
\\
&\qquad \sim
a(s-a) - \frac 12a(b+c) + \frac 12a^2
\\
&\qquad \sim
(s-a) - \frac 12(2s-a) + \frac 12a
\\
&\qquad =0\ .
%
%
%
\\[3mm]
&y_N + z_N \\
&\qquad =(s-a)[(s-c)^3+(s-b)^3]\\
&\qquad =(s-a)(2s-b-c)[(s-b)^2 -(s-b)(s-c) + (s-c)^2]\\
&\qquad =a(s-a)\cdot \frac 14[ a^2  + 3(b-c)^2]
\\[3mm]
&x_N + y_N + z_N \\
&\qquad = a(s-a)\cdot \frac 14[ a^2  + 3(b-c)^2] + a^2(s-b)(s-c)\ ,
\\[3mm]
&(s-a)^2x_N + (s-b)^2y_N + (s-c)^2z_N \\
&\qquad = -\frac 14 a(s-a)(s - b)(s - c)
(a^2 + b^2  + c^2 - 2ab - 2bc - 2ca)
\\[3mm]
&a^2y_Nz_N +
b^2z_Nx_N +
c^2x_Ny_N \\
&\qquad =a^2(s-a)^2(s-b)^3(s-c)^3 + a^2b^2(s-a)(s-b)^4(s-c) + a^2c^2(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)^4\\
&\qquad =a^2(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\Big(\ (s-a)(s-b)^2(s-c)^2 + b^2(s-b)^3 +c^2(s-c)^3\ \Big)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and it turns out that in the last parenthesis one can factor
$(a^2 + b^2  + c^2 - 2ab - 2bc - 2ca)$,
and finally $(\diamondsuit)$ is satisfied.

---

It remains to compute the squared distances $NB^2$ and $NC^2$, and to show the corresponding proportionality $NB^2:NC^2=KB^2:KC^2=(s-b)^2:(s-c)^2$.
Let us compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
N &= [x_N:y_N:z_N] =\left(\ \frac{x_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{y_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{z_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ \right)\ ,
\\
B &=(0,1,0)\ ,
\\
\overrightarrow{BN} &= N-B\\
&=\left(\ \frac{x_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{y_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{z_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ \right)-(0,1,0)\\
&=\left(\ \frac{x_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{-x_N-z_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{z_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ \right)
\ ,
\\
NB^2
&=-\frac {a^2(-x_N-z_N)z_N + b^2z_Nx_N + c^2x_N(-x_N-z_N) }{(x_N+y_N+z_N)^2}
\\
\overrightarrow{CN} &= N-C\\
&=\left(\ \frac{x_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{y_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{z_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ \right)-(0,0,1)\\
&=\left(\ \frac{x_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{y_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ ,\ \frac{-x_N-y_N}{x_N+y_N+z_N}\ \right)
\ ,
\\
NC^2
&=-\frac {a^2y_N(-x_N-y_N) + b^2(-x_N-y_N)x_N + c^2x_Ny_N }{(x_N+y_N+z_N)^2}
\\
\end{aligned}
$$
So we have to show the equality:
$$
\ (s-c)^2\Big(\ a^2(x_N+z_N)z_N - b^2x_Nz_N + c^2(x_N+z_N)x_N\ )
\\
=
(s-b)^2\Big(\ a^2(x_N+y_N)y_N + b^2(x_N+y_N)x_N -c^2x_Ny_N\ )
\ .
$$
This can be shown by computing the above as a polynomial in $x_N$...

---

Let us give the short computer proof on the above lines.

```
var('a,b,c,x,y,z');
s = (a + b + c)/2

eq_incircle = 0 == - a^2*y*z - b^2*z*x - c^2*x*y + (x + y + z)*((s-a)^2*x + (s-b)^2*y + (s-c)^2*z)
eq_KM       = 0 == matrix(3, 3, [x, y, z, 0, s-c, s-b, 2*a^2, a^2+b^2-c^2, a^2-b^2+c^2]).det()

xn, yn, zn = a^2*(s-b)*(s-c), (s-a)*(s-c)^3, (s-a)*(s-b)^3

dicn = {x : xn, y : yn, z : zn}

print(f'Is N on the incircle? {bool(eq_incircle.subs(dicn))}.')
print(f'Is N on the line KM ? {bool(eq_KM      .subs(dicn))}.')
```

The above sage code delivers:

```
Is N on the incircle? True.
Is N on the line KM ? True.
```

It is also easy to check distances proportion.

```
N = vector([xn, yn, zn]) / (xn + yn + zn)
B = vector([0, 1, 0])
C = vector([0, 0, 1])

def dist_squared(displacement):
    x, y, z = displacement
    return -a^2*y*z -b^2*z*x -c^2*x*y 

eq_angle_bisector = dist_squared(N - B) / dist_squared(N - C) == (s-b)^2 / (s-c)^2

print(f'Is N so that NB:NC = KB:KC? {bool(eq_angle_bisector.subs(dicn))}.')
```

And we get:

```
Is N so that NB:NC = KB:KC? True.
```

$\square$

Comment: I finished the proof by Cartesian coordinates: https://github.com/auntyellow/math/blob/main/contest.md#tangency-of-an-incircle-and-a-circumcircle

Answer (score 0):

As OP points out in the comments, the question arises from problem G7 in an [IMO Short-listed Problems and Solutions](https://anhngq.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/imo-2002-shortlist.pdf) document (also [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140904032451/https://anhngq.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/imo-2002-shortlist.pdf)). On pg 19, Solution 2 for that problem demonstrates that $NK$ bisects $\angle BNC.$

Answer (score 0):

Here I'd like to provide two solutions: a synthetic one and a coordinate one.

#### Synthetic Solution

This solution is mentioned in a famous series of IMO training books in China, ISBN: 9787542850393, the *Analytic Geometry* part, provided by [Libing Huang](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Libing-Huang-3).

The solution uses some projective geometry knowledges and looks much simpler than two solutions in the original [IMO 2002 shortlist](https://anhngq.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/imo-2002-shortlist.pdf) G7. There are many additional points and lines added so some letters are changed:

[image]

*D*, *E* and *F* are tangent points of incircle (*I*) to edges *BC*, *CA* and *AF* respectively; *AH* is the altitude and *M* its the midpoint; *D* and *N* are intersections of (*I*) and *DM*. Prove *ND* bisects $\angle BNC$.

1. Make $P=BC\cap EF$, such that *P* is on *D*'s polar *BC* and *A*'s polar *EF*, then according to [this](https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=polePolarBrianchonBrokard) (Theorem 6), *P* is the pole of *AD*.
2. Make *Q* the other intersection of (*I*) and *PN*, and make $R=PQ\cap AD$, then according to [this](https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=polePolarBrianchonBrokard) (Theorem 7), $(P,N;R,Q)=-1$.
3. Make $S=AH\cap QD$, then $(H,M;A,S)=(P,N;R,Q)=-1$ through perspective center *D*. Because $AM=MH$, *S* must a point at infinity, then $AH//QD$, then $PQ\perp ND$.
4. Make $T=PE\cap AD$, then $(P,F;T,E)=-1$, then $(P,B;D,C)=(P,F;T,E)=-1$ through perspective center *A*. According to [this](https://imomath.com/index.cgi?page=problemsInProjectiveGeometry) (Problem 2), *ND* bisects $\angle BNC$.

#### Coordinate Solution

I just use the above diagram, then put *D* onto origin and *BC* onto x-axis. Then set $B=(-b,0)$, $C=(c,0)$ and $I=(0,r)$. Solve *F* by the fact that *D* and *F* are the two intersection of two circles:

$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2-2ry=0\\x^2+2bx+y^2=0\end{cases}$$

Then solve *E* analogously, then get *A*, *M* and *N*, then their coordinates are:

$$F=\left(-\frac{2br^2}{b^2+r^2},\frac{2b^2r}{b^2+r^2}\right)\\E=\left(\frac{2cr^2}{c^2+r^2},\frac{2c^2r}{c^2+r^2}\right)\\A=\left(\frac{(b-c)r^2}{bc-r^2},\frac{2bcr}{bc-r^2}\right)\\M=\left(\frac{(b-c)r^2}{bc-r^2},\frac{bcr}{bc-r^2}\right)\\N=\left(\frac{2bc(b-c)r^2}{b^2c^2+b^2r^2-2bcr^2+c^2r^2},\frac{2b^2c^2r}{b^2c^2+b^2r^2-2bcr^2+c^2r^2}\right)$$

So it's easy to prove $BN:BD=CN:CD$.